# How do I change the language of Artisan?

Tags: laravel-artisan

Whenever I get error messages with Artistan, they display partly in Italian, I think. EG

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1072 La 'company' existe pas dans la table
```

I can pretty much make out what it says, but I don't want to leave anything to chance. How can I change this?

Note, other parts appear to be in English. a `php artisan` lists all results in English.

Comment: That looks like French to me (and it should be `n'existe` IIRC). Could it be that it is reading your locale? For other parts appearing in English, that could be because those phrases aren't localized, I guess.

Comment: @watery Yeah that's the one! I didn't see the n' there. My location is set to Australia though so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: FYI, the message is in French and can be translated to "The 'company' doesn't exist in the table"